# Rigid body and Zero gravity

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I need to animate set of rigid bodies with zero gravity. I don't want to cancel gravity in the scene since I need it for other rigid bodies.

How can I "say" to specific rigid bodies in the scene not to "listen" for the scene gravity?

Comment: I think this may help...

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122506/blender-2-8-restrict-influence-of-force-field-to-its-collection

Comment: Yes, this is relevant for particles, but I have a Rigid Body. There is no such setting for it.

Comment: Could you not do it in 2 stages?  Allow the object in question it's low gravity in a temporary Blend file, bake that action, then append that file to the main project, importing the object and it's keyframed action.

Comment: Wow! Sounds like there is no build-in function to do that, isn't it? Anyway, thank you for the idea!