# How to limit the force field only on a specified area?

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields

I want to apply a force only on particles in a specified area, so they go upwards in their path (see pictures). I tried to use a wind force field, but that seems to affect all particles no matter where they are. Is there a better solution or can I limit the affect range of the force field?
I know that there is a similar thread already but moving the particles in a different collection is no use for my case.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is [Restrict influence of Force Field to its Collection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122506/blender-2-8-restrict-influence-of-force-field-to-its-collection/155770#155770) not an option?

Comment: You see I want the particles to go down into the turbine and on the sides with help of a force field back up. I would need a way to first assign the particles to the collection when they are on the sides and then unassign them when they should fall down in the middle.

Comment: Ok, I see. How should the particles go in your scene when the fan is rotating? In the shape of a horizontal 8? You can make a *Wind* force field with a curve shape. Then the particles will follow the path. Not sure if it works for your setup ("8"). Or you can use the Force Field *Curve Type*. But in my test, I couldn't speed up the particles. It also looks like there are some known issues and it's subject to change in future versions of blender.